# Error when using placeholder in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got this error when using the code below (everything is in a try catch block):

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens

```
$item_q = 4;
$item_no = 12;

$update = $db->prepare("UPDATE stock 
  SET quantity = quantity - :item_q 
  WHERE item_number = :item_no");

$update->execute([':item_q' => $item_q]);
$update->execute([':item_no' => $item_no]);
```

It is something with the :item_q that is causing problem and i do not what it is. It works when I replace the :item_q in the sql query with a number. I am happy for some help! :)

Comment: Don't execute two times !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

Currently you're executing twice with one parameter bound each time.

## Solution

You want to either bind the parameters first then execute, or execute with both parameters bound.

**Executing with both bound values in** `PDOStatement::execute()` **function**

```
$update->execute([":item_q" => $item_q, ":item_num" => $item_no]);
```

**Executing after binding parameters with** `PDOStatement::bindParam()` **function**

```
$update->bindParam(":item_q", $item_q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->bindParam(":item_num", $item_no, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$update->execute();
```

Comment: @Yngfors No worries, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

Problem is with executing your statement two times.

```
$update->execute([':item_q' => $item_q]);
$update->execute([':item_no' => $item_no]);
```

Combine it into one as

```
$update->execute([':item_q' => $item_q,':item_no' => $item_no]);
```

Comment: Is your array key `item_no` missing a colon before it or am I missing something? Should it be `:item_no` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**  and let me know if it doesn't work

```
 $update->execute([':item_q' => $item_q,':item_no' => $item_no]);
```